# Windows 10 Creating new window with initial size

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-10

I'm trying to create a new window in my Windows 10 application but I want to be able to specify the initial size for the created window.

So far I'm trying as so, with no luck -

```
            var currentAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

            var newCoreAppView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            await newCoreAppView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                          CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                          async () =>
                          {
                              var newWindow = Window.Current;
                              var newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
                              newAppView.SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(1, 1));
                              newAppView.TryResizeView(new Size(300, 300));
                              newAppView.Title = "New small window";

                              var frame = new Frame();
                              frame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage), null);
                              newWindow.Content = frame;
                              newWindow.Activate();

                              await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
                                    newAppView.Id,
                                    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum,
                                    currentAppView.Id,
                                    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);
                          });
```

Comment: What is the outcome?

Comment: This currently creates a window the same size as the original. The aim here would be to create window of size 300x300.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885979/windows-10-uwp-app-setting-window-size-on-desktop#31888254) answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Resize the window after it's shown.

```
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
    newAppView.Id,
    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum,
    currentAppView.Id,
    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);

newAppView.TryResizeView(new Size(300, 300));
```

Comment: Whilst this does work, occasionally it shows the splash screen at the same size before resizing which can be jarring. Also this can cause the app to reopen from scratch at the smaller size unfortunately