# Windows 10 UAP change window size

Tags: c#, windows-10

How can I change the default minimum window size for my application?

I think it can be here:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 UWP app - Setting window size on desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885979/windows-10-uwp-app-setting-window-size-on-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(300, 200);
```

Just that in the forms constructor... If it is a Windows Forms application of course.

I missed it was UAP. Just do what you said from that namespace:

```
SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(300, 200))
```