# How to set min size of windows universal app on desktop?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I would like to set min size like 800x600 for my windows universal app which on desktop.

I found a method

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(800, 600));
```

but it doesn't work, I still can drag the window to 500x300.

What I miss ?

Comment: In which method you wrote this line of code?

Comment: I was follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885979/windows-10-uwp-app-setting-window-size-on-desktop

Comment: This is really strange...

Comment: do you have any ideas ?

Comment: try to write the code into a try-catch(Exception ex) block and move it to the OnNavigateTo method.. Hit F5 and check if throw any exception.. Not sure it's going to work though, it's just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview

for desktop, I can set a min size which is bigger than 500x500 as below code.

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width < 800 || e.NewSize.Height < 600)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(800, 600));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. A small improvement is here: ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(Math.Max(800, e.NewSize.Width), Math.Max(600, e.NewSize.Height)));

Comment: This works, but it look very bad. As user is dragging, the window actually gets smaller than specified and there's flickering as the code "fights" the user. There must be a better way. It's so bizarre that MS would hard code this to 500x500 and not let the developer change it.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you
>   set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the
>   allowed bounds.

Maybe this is the reason

[MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: so it's only able to set more smaller ?

Comment: It should works if you set the size to 500,500.. Can you confirm?

Comment: try to post a request on Windows Feedback, there is a section for developers

Answer (score 0):

For my app I am setting it to run on the Desktop at a startup height of 480 and a width of 320.

On my Mainpage's code behind file I call the following method:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
      GetDeviceFormFactorType();
    }


       public static DeviceFormFactorType GetDeviceFormFactorType()
    {
        switch (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily)
        {
            case "Windows.Mobile":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Phone;
            case "Windows.Desktop":
                ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 320, Height = 480 });
                ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Height = 480, Width = 320 };
                ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Desktop;
            case "Windows.Tablet":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Tablet;
            case "Windows.Universal":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Iot;
            case "Windows.Team":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.SurfaceHub;
            default:
                return DeviceFormFactorType.other;
        }
    }


        public enum DeviceFormFactorType
    {
        Phone,
        Desktop,
        Tablet,
        Iot,
        SurfaceHub,
        other
    }
```